# Change SVG When Hovering Menu In Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I'm making a `bootstrap-inverse` menu, however, I want to make it so when you hover the menu, the SVG logo I have changes to `fill: #fff;` instead of it being the default `#000` color that is by default. Currently, my code follows:

```css
   .navbar-inverse:hover {
background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar__home navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="menu">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nav-modal" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
            <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered"><svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="297.000000pt" height="51.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 297.000000 51.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,51.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M0 255 l0 -245 55 0 55 0 0 100 0 100 75 0 75 0 0 35 0 35 -75 0 -75
0 0 75 0 75 84 0 c78 0 84 1 90 23 13 48 14 47 -139 47 l-145 0 0 -245z"/>
<path d="M350 255 l0 -245 55 0 55 0 0 95 0 95 28 0 c24 0 32 -11 77 -95 l50
-95 58 0 c31 0 57 2 57 5 0 2 -27 48 -60 102 -51 84 -57 99 -44 108 68 43 92
93 80 161 -16 82 -88 114 -261 114 l-95 0 0 -245z m205 161 c37 -16 52 -48 41
-92 -8 -29 -57 -54 -106 -54 l-30 0 0 80 0 80 30 0 c17 0 46 -6 65 -14z"/>
<path d="M790 255 l0 -245 150 0 150 0 0 35 0 35 -95 0 -95 0 0 75 0 75 75 0
75 0 0 35 0 35 -75 0 -75 0 0 65 0 65 90 0 c82 0 90 2 90 19 0 11 3 26 6 35 5
14 -11 16 -145 16 l-151 0 0 -245z"/>
<path d="M1170 255 l0 -245 150 0 150 0 0 35 0 35 -95 0 -95 0 0 75 0 75 75 0
75 0 0 35 0 35 -75 0 -75 0 0 65 0 65 90 0 c82 0 90 2 90 19 0 11 3 26 6 35 5
14 -11 16 -145 16 l-151 0 0 -245z"/>
<path d="M1550 255 l0 -245 55 0 55 0 0 100 0 100 75 0 75 0 0 35 0 35 -75 0
-75 0 0 75 0 75 84 0 c78 0 84 1 90 23 13 48 14 47 -139 47 l-145 0 0 -245z"/>
<path d="M1882 262 c-40 -130 -73 -241 -72 -245 0 -4 24 -7 52 -5 l53 3 14 52
14 53 78 0 78 0 12 -55 12 -55 58 0 57 0 -17 58 c-10 31 -44 141 -76 245 l-58
187 -66 0 -66 0 -73 -238z"/>
<path d="M2290 255 l0 -246 147 3 148 3 6 38 6 37 -99 0 -98 0 0 205 0 205
-55 0 -55 0 0 -245z"/>
<path d="M2650 255 l0 -246 147 3 148 3 6 38 6 37 -99 0 -98 0 0 205 0 205
-55 0 -55 0 0 -245z"/>
</g>
</svg>
</div>

        </div>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered category-tabs">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li data-toggle="modal" class="boxed" data-target="#nav-modal"><a class="ion-drag" style="font-size:32px;"></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You need to create a working demo with the issue you are facing.

Comment: @hunzaboy It's just the default navbar at the moment. I just want to make it so when you hover over navbar reverse, the background changes to white, the navbar links change to #333, and the SVG logo changes to a different color, but nothing I try works )):

Comment: You code shows nothing except the svg. We cannot help you properly without seeing anything. Try to create a fiddle and put your code into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the structure is not having **navbar-inverse** and you want to fill svg element instead of div, so target element you want to change.

```css
   .navbar-brand:hover svg path {
fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar__home navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="menu">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nav-modal" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
            <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered"><svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="297.000000pt" height="51.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 297.000000 51.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,51.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M0 255 l0 -245 55 0 55 0 0 100 0 100 75 0 75 0 0 35 0 35 -75 0 -75
0 0 75 0 75 84 0 c78 0 84 1 90 23 13 48 14 47 -139 47 l-145 0 0 -245z"/>
<path d="M350 255 l0 -245 55 0 55 0 0 95 0 95 28 0 c24 0 32 -11 77 -95 l50
-95 58 0 c31 0 57 2 57 5 0 2 -27 48 -60 102 -51 84 -57 99 -44 108 68 43 92
93 80 161 -16 82 -88 114 -261 114 l-95 0 0 -245z m205 161 c37 -16 52 -48 41
-92 -8 -29 -57 -54 -106 -54 l-30 0 0 80 0 80 30 0 c17 0 46 -6 65 -14z"/>
<path d="M790 255 l0 -245 150 0 150 0 0 35 0 35 -95 0 -95 0 0 75 0 75 75 0
75 0 0 35 0 35 -75 0 -75 0 0 65 0 65 90 0 c82 0 90 2 90 19 0 11 3 26 6 35 5
14 -11 16 -145 16 l-151 0 0 -245z"/>
<path d="M1170 255 l0 -245 150 0 150 0 0 35 0 35 -95 0 -95 0 0 75 0 75 75 0
75 0 0 35 0 35 -75 0 -75 0 0 65 0 65 90 0 c82 0 90 2 90 19 0 11 3 26 6 35 5
14 -11 16 -145 16 l-151 0 0 -245z"/>
<path d="M1550 255 l0 -245 55 0 55 0 0 100 0 100 75 0 75 0 0 35 0 35 -75 0
-75 0 0 75 0 75 84 0 c78 0 84 1 90 23 13 48 14 47 -139 47 l-145 0 0 -245z"/>
<path d="M1882 262 c-40 -130 -73 -241 -72 -245 0 -4 24 -7 52 -5 l53 3 14 52
14 53 78 0 78 0 12 -55 12 -55 58 0 57 0 -17 58 c-10 31 -44 141 -76 245 l-58
187 -66 0 -66 0 -73 -238z"/>
<path d="M2290 255 l0 -246 147 3 148 3 6 38 6 37 -99 0 -98 0 0 205 0 205
-55 0 -55 0 0 -245z"/>
<path d="M2650 255 l0 -246 147 3 148 3 6 38 6 37 -99 0 -98 0 0 205 0 205
-55 0 -55 0 0 -245z"/>
</g>
</svg>
</div>

        </div>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered category-tabs">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li data-toggle="modal" class="boxed" data-target="#nav-modal"><a class="ion-drag" style="font-size:32px;"></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Just to clarify why this works and your answer doesn't. This answer changed your selector from .navbar-inverse:hover to .navbar-brand:hover svg path. The class .navbar-inverse, didn't apply to any elements on your HTML page. It also targets the path elements in the SVG element.

Comment: Ok. I will explain

Comment: Thanks! We just want to make sure we add explanations to our answers so that people can understand where their mistakes are.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably late to the party but you want to change the fill of the svg.

This is the correct css:

```
svg:hover path {
    fill: red;
}
```